# How to crop text around a searchword exluding HTML-tags

Tags: php, html

What I have is a string containing HTML and Text, also theres a searchword.
I want to get some cropped Text "around" the $searchword.

Example Text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <sometag>At</sometag> vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Output if the $searchword is "vero":

```
...sed diam voluptua. At <strong>vero</strong> eos et accusam et...
```

So I want X chars before and after the searchword excluding HTML.
I dont know how to start. I know we need a substr function and a regex maybe, but I am stuck.

Comment: What do you mean with "X chars before and after the searchword"? In your example you simply wrap th searchword with the `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim's solution works fine, but here's a slightly different solution matching m characters before and n characters after the given word instead of n words:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <sometag>At</sometag> vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
$string = strip_tags($string); // strip html tags
$word = 'vero';
$replace = "<strong>$word</strong>";
$before = 22; // characters to match before word
$after = 7; // characters to match after word

preg_match('/(.){'.$before.'}'.$word.'(.){'.$after.'}/', $string, $matches);

echo '...' . preg_replace('/'.$word.'/', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $matches[0]) . '...';
// returns "...sed diam voluptua. At <strong>vero</strong> eos et..." for $before = 22 and $after = 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// The string to search in
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ex.';

// The text to search
$search_query = 'consectetur';

// The regular expression
// Note that I’m using preg_quote() to make sure the text doesn’t conflict with the regular expression
// This expression matches 3 words (punctuation included) before and after the searched keyword
$search = '/((\w+[^\w]+){3})(' . preg_quote($search_query) . ')(([^\w]+\w+){3})/i';

// Find all matches of the expression, and store it in $matches
preg_match($search, $text, $matches);

// Use the results to generate the string you desire.
$result = sprintf('...%s<strong>%s</strong>%s...', $matches[1], $matches[3], $matches[4]);
```

Comment: hmm the only problem is the HTML tags... its possible they appear in the $result :(

Comment: You can use the php's `strip_tags` method

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Removing HTML tags. Step 2: Wrapping the searchword occurrences.

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <sometag>At</sometag> vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';

$plainText = strip_tags($text);

$resultText = str_replace($searchword, '<strong>' . $searchword . '</strong>', $plainText);
```